Installing Docker container for Java Spring Postgres application. Connection to localhost:5432 refused
Error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
I am trying to deploy my first docker container. It is a simple Java Spring REST API application.
It runs fine in Eclipse. I can connect to the database using SQL Explorer just fine.
I tried Telnet and Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -Port 5432 in Powershell and it returns

ComputerName     : localhost RemoteAddress    : ::1 RemotePort       :
5432 InterfaceAlias   : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 SourceAddress    :
::1 TcpTestSucceeded : True

Using JDK 17. Postgres 16. OS: Windows 10. Postgres service is running fine.
I tried everything I can find but I cannot make it succeed. I am 100% new to docker.
Docker fails after running: docker compose up --build
Full Exception:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432
refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the
postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. server-1  |     at
org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:342)
~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2] server-1  |     at
org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2] server-1  |     at
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:263)
~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2] server-1  |     at
org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2] server-1  |     at
org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2] server-1  |     at
com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na] server-1  |     at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na] server-1  |     at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na] server-1  |     at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na] server-1  |     at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na] server-1  |     at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:100)
~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na] server-1  |     at
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:428)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:61)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:276)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.(Database.java:45)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:170)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503)
~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366)
~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833)
~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234)
~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952)
~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4] server-1  |     at
com.robbank.crudApis.RobbankCrudApiApplication.main(RobbankCrudApiApplication.java:10)
~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] server-1  |     at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method) ~[na:na] server-1  |     at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
Source) ~[na:na] server-1  |     at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
Source) ~[na:na] server-1  |     at
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
server-1  |     at
org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91)
~[file:/:na] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53)
~[file:/:na] server-1  |     at
org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
~[file:/:na]

Compose.yaml (auto generated):
# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Docker Compose reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-spec-reference/

# Here the instructions define your application as a service called "server".
# This service is built from the Dockerfile in the current directory.
# You can add other services your application may depend on here, such as a
# database or a cache. For examples, see the Awesome Compose repository:
# https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

# The commented out section below is an example of how to define a PostgreSQL
# database that your application can use. `depends_on` tells Docker Compose to
# start the database before your application. The `db-data` volume persists the
# database data between container restarts. The `db-password` secret is used
# to set the database password. You must create `db/password.txt` and add
# a password of your choosing to it before running `docker-compose up`.
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"  # Map container port 5432 to host port 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: robbankdb
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres  # Set the superuser username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Password01  # Set the superuser password
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    expose:
      - 5432
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  db-data:  # Define a named volume for database data persistence

application.properties:
spring.application.name=RobbankCrudApi

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/robbankdb
spring.datasource.username=robbankuser
spring.datasource.password=rob123

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.show-sql=true 

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public

spring.jackson.serialization.indent-output=true

server.error.include-message=always 

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.robbank.crudApis</groupId>
    <artifactId>RobbankCrudApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RobbankCrudApi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Dockerfile (auto generated)
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

# Want to help us make this template better? Share your feedback here: https://forms.gle/ybq9Krt8jtBL3iCk7

################################################################################

# Create a stage for resolving and downloading dependencies.
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy as deps

WORKDIR /build

# Copy the mvnw wrapper with executable permissions.
COPY --chmod=0755 mvnw mvnw
COPY .mvn/ .mvn/

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.m2 so that subsequent builds don't have to
# re-download packages.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=pom.xml,target=pom.xml \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -DskipTests

################################################################################

# Create a stage for building the application based on the stage with downloaded dependencies.
# This Dockerfile is optimized for Java applications that output an uber jar, which includes
# all the dependencies needed to run your app inside a JVM. If your app doesn't output an uber
# jar and instead relies on an application server like Apache Tomcat, you'll need to update this
# stage with the correct filename of your package and update the base image of the "final" stage
# use the relevant app server, e.g., using tomcat (https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) as a base image.
FROM deps as package

WORKDIR /build

COPY ./src src/
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=pom.xml,target=pom.xml \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 \
    ./mvnw package -DskipTests && \
    mv target/$(./mvnw help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout)-$(./mvnw help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout).jar target/app.jar

################################################################################

# Create a stage for extracting the application into separate layers.
# Take advantage of Spring Boot's layer tools and Docker's caching by extracting
# the packaged application into separate layers that can be copied into the final stage.
# See Spring's docs for reference:
# https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/container-images.html
FROM package as extract

WORKDIR /build

RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/app.jar extract --destination target/extracted

################################################################################

# Create a new stage for running the application that contains the minimal
# runtime dependencies for the application. This often uses a different base
# image from the install or build stage where the necessary files are copied
# from the install stage.
#
# The example below uses eclipse-turmin's JRE image as the foundation for running the app.
# By specifying the "17-jre-jammy" tag, it will also use whatever happens to be the
# most recent version of that tag when you build your Dockerfile.
# If reproducability is important, consider using a specific digest SHA, like
# eclipse-temurin@sha256:99cede493dfd88720b610eb8077c8688d3cca50003d76d1d539b0efc8cca72b4.
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy AS final

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser
USER appuser

# Copy the executable from the "package" stage.
COPY --from=extract build/target/extracted/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=extract build/target/extracted/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=extract build/target/extracted/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=extract build/target/extracted/application/ ./

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher" ]


Can you try changing your spring boot application datasource username and password to root password that you have used in docker-compose yaml.

You are running inside a docker container, hence the database is not on localhost as that would be inside the container. You need to use a network in docker to communicate with the other container and use the name of the container instead of localhost or use a docker compose file (to get the network automatically) and still use the container name. This question has been answered numerous times before so you might want to use the search function as well.

your serve and db are running in different docker container, each container has its own IP address, so you can't use localhost to connect db ,you should use the db container ip to connect.

Hi PitPan, what address can I use? How can I run postgres in a different ip? ipconfig returns nothing.

You can use docker inspect --format '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <CONTAINER_NAME> to get the container ipaddress. Also , you can use docker create network <network_name> to create a docker network ,then use docker network connect <network_name> <container_name> to connect your db and serve to same docker network, after this step your use container name to replace localhost.Moreover,different container in same docker network are also different ipaddress, use docker network inspect <your_network_name>you can see the container in this network`s ipaddress
